# Specifying classes loading order in @ContextConfiguration in JUnit test cases

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I am using junit 4.11  and spring-test-4.1.5 for writing integration test cases. I am using @ContextConfiguration annotation to load the configurations.like,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes ={ApplicationConfig.class,SpringConfiguration.class }, initializers = {CustomProfileResolver.class, AppInitializer.class}, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

As you can see i am using two configuration classes.
The problem i am facing is **i want to load the `SpringConfiguration.class` before  `ApplicationConfig.class`**. I tried with reversing the order but it didn't worked. Neither @order can be specified here.

So how to order the loading of these configuration classes, is it possible ?

Comment: You're probably better off defining a single configuration class, e.g. `TestConfig.class` in which you `@Import` the other relevant configs, e.g. `@Import({ApplicationConfig.class,SpringConfiguration.class}) public class TestConfig {}`

Comment: @Anand j. Kadhi, what is the maven dependency of your SpringConfiguration.class?

Answer (score 4):

Use @ContextHierarchy

```
@ContextHierarchy({
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringConfiguration.class}),
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfig.class})
}
```

Comment: where can I find SpringConfiguration.class? And what maven dependency?

Answer (score 3):

`@ContextConfiguration` and its supporting classes (e.g., `MergedContextConfiguration`, `AnnotationConfigContextLoader`, `AbstractTestContextBootstrapper`, etc.) are intended to retain the original ordering of `@Configuration` classes declared via the `classes` attribute of `@ContextConfiguration`.

Thus, if you can verifiably prove that reversing the order of your `SpringConfiguration` and `ApplicationConfig` classes does not result in `SpringConfiguration` being processed first, then you have found a bug in Spring.

If you have found a bug, please report it in [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR).

Thanks,

Sam